# Check is JSON is a valid Swagger or not

Tags: java, swagger

I have a `javax.json.Json` object which I need to validate if its a valid Swagger file or not. I wrote these utility functions -

```
package com.somecompany.gis.util;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.StringWriter;
import java.util.Map;

import javax.json.Json;
import javax.json.JsonObject;
import javax.json.JsonWriter;

import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

import io.swagger.models.Swagger;
import io.swagger.parser.SwaggerParser;



public class Converter {
public static JsonNode toJsonNode(JsonObject jsonObject) throws IOException {

    // Parse a JsonObject into a JSON string
    StringWriter stringWriter = new StringWriter();
    try (JsonWriter jsonWriter = Json.createWriter(stringWriter)) {
        jsonWriter.writeObject(jsonObject);
    }
    String json = stringWriter.toString();

    // Parse a JSON string into a JsonNode
    ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
    JsonNode jsonNode = objectMapper.readTree(json);

    return jsonNode;
}

    public static boolean isValidSwaggerSpec(JsonObject jsonObject) {
    try {
        JsonNode jsonNode = toJsonNode(jsonObject);
        Swagger swagger = new SwaggerParser().read(jsonNode);
        return true;
    }catch(IOException ioe) {
        return false;
    }catch(Exception e) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

However, I see that even with an invalid Swagger file, i get an evaluation of `true`. Is there any way I can check if a Swagger is valid or not?

Comment: It does not appear that [`SwaggerParser#read`](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-parser/blob/7d23dc34c299e29a0c64fbc7d250816308f8842e/modules/swagger-parser/src/main/java/io/swagger/parser/SwaggerParser.java#L132) throws any exceptions, does it return `null` when you provide an invalid configuration? What version of Swagger spec do you want to validate?

Comment: @Mark what do you mean by invalid configuration? You mean an invalid swagger doc? I was expecting `ParseException` on reading invalid JSON. But no such exception. However, most getters of the Swagger provide me `null`.

Comment: Is this for Swagger specification 1.x, 2.x or 3.x?

Comment: @Mark "swagger":"2.0"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to use [SwaggerParser#readWithInfo](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-parser/blob/7d23dc34c299e29a0c64fbc7d250816308f8842e/modules/swagger-parser/src/main/java/io/swagger/parser/SwaggerParser.java#L89) which returns a `SwaggerDeserializationResult` object, when an error occurs they fill the `List<String> messages` of that object with a specific message:

```
return new SwaggerDeserializationResult().message("empty or null swagger supplied");
result = new SwaggerDeserializationResult().message("Definition does not appear to be a valid Swagger format");
return new SwaggerDeserializationResult().message("malformed or unreadable swagger supplied");
```

You can check for these sentences and make sure it's *none* of those, this should mean that it successfully parsed.

---

```
SwaggerDeserializationResult swagger = new SwaggerParser().readWithInfo(myJSONString);
List<String> messages = swagger.getMessages();

// Check if messages contains any of those strings
```

Comment: will check in 13 hours. Just switched off my laptop :P